# Can I safely extend javascript builtin classes?

Tags: javascript, class

Can I safely extend Javascript builtin classes, like `Array`?

I.e. on which browsers/environments will the following not work:

```
Array.prototype.double = function() { return  this.concat(this); }
Array.twice = function(a) { return a.double(); }
Array.twice([1, 2, 3]) # => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is a common practice, and I believe it will work everywhere. I won't post as an answer though, as someone else may be able to confirm for certain that it will never cause you problems.

Comment: @Michael Just adding that `Object.prototype` is the only one that is off limits. Anyone using `for..in` to loop over arrays deserves to be tripped over. I will not add an answer as I couldn't possibly test on ALL browsers.

Comment: Andrew Dupont [gave a nice JSConf presentation](http://blip.tv/jsconf/jsconf2011-andrew-dupont-everything-is-permitted-extending-built-ins-5211542) on this topic.

Comment: @Esailija anyone using `for..in` on objects also deserves to be tripped over ;)

Comment: I would recommend reading [What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) and of course [Don’t modify objects you don’t own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)!

Comment: @Pierre: As for DOM objects - that's a different "type" of objects, though - host objects, not built-ins. See this other post by the same author: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Comment: @Pierre extending DOM isn't a "problem" as such. It's more of a "experts only" thing. [DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "work".

There are three main issues with prototype extension.

- it's global scope so there is name collision
- If your adding enumerable properties it breaks `for .. in`
- Code is confusing to read, is this an ES5 feature or a custom library?

It will work as in, `Array.prototype` and `Array` are mutable so you can add the code and call the properties.

However:

```
Array.prototype.trolls = 42;
for (var k in []) {
  alert(k === "trolls");
}
```

The above is an example of it breaking `for .. in`. This is easily solved with

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "trolls", {
  value: ...,
  enumerable: false
});
```

(ES5 only. Breaks in IE<9. can't be emulated in legacy engines)

or with

```
for (var k in []) {
  if ([].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    alert(k === "trolls");
  }
}
```

Personally I avoid automatically extending natives for these exact reasons. However I think it's perfectly acceptable to have a `.extendNatives` function in your library like [`pd.extendNatives`](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.extendNatives)

Comment: +1 @Raynos we can always count on you for excellent JavaScript answers.

Comment: [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) does this professionally. I think it can be beneficial in a controlled environment (i.e. your own web-app) and acceptable if done right in a library.

Comment: @Tomalak extending natives isn't "bad" as such. I do frown upon doing this by default, it's best if placed behind an `extendNatives` function. I don't think it's acceptable to do in library if your library isn't a native object extension library. Extending native objects as a side effect in a library is bad. The only possible case where Extending native objects as a side effect is acceptable if they shim parts of the ES5 spec and are 100% compliant.

Comment: Agreed. Doing it without telling anybody (i.e., as a side effect) is a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Safely, not really - because you can't be sure you're the only one extending them, or that you're actually extending the correct methods (see Prototype - last time I checked, it was extending the builtin classes, which wreaked havoc on others scripts' expectations of the builtins' behavior). Modifying objects you don't own is a path to very tricky territory ("oh, but is this the actual built-in `concat()`, or did some other script change it behind our back?").

See e.g. this for a more detailed discussion: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/