# Extending Promise base class typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to extend Promise base class, with a static method and an instance method.
I am having trouble with the typescript definitions.
See my code below!

```
declare global {
    class PromiseConstructor {
        static timeout(): null;
    }
    interface Promise<T> {
        timeout(): null
        finally<T>(f: () => void): Promise<T>,
    }

}

Promise.timeout = (n: number) => {
  // code...
}

Promise.prototype.finally = function (onFinally) {
  // code...
};
```

With this code, when I try to defined `Promise.timeout` above, typescript gives me the error : `Property timeout is a static member of type PromiseConstructor`.

If I try to define the typing `timeout()` inside the `interface Promise` block, typescript gives me the error `'static' modifier cannot appear on a type member`.

How can I type the timeout method?

Comment: [Don't!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40342870/1048572)

Comment: Please don't stick new functions on globals, make a module and import the functions from there.

Comment: I'm doing it still :)

Comment: Fully agree with @Bergi: don't do it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know that you would have to extend from `interface PromiseConstructor` instead of a `class PromiseConstructor`.

```js
declare global {
  interface PromiseConstructor {
    timeout(n: number): any;
  }
}
```