# Extend array prototype correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a groupBy method with which I would like to extend Array.

```
const groupBy = <T>(array: T[], predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => string) =>
  array.reduce((acc, value, index, array) => {
    (acc[predicate(value, index, array)] ||= []).push(value);
    return acc;
  }, {} as { [key: string]: T[] });
```

I found the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64489535/7514409), and I'm trying to enable my arrays to operate like `const groupItems = myItems.groupBy(item => item.key)`.

I have the basic extension code setup, along with a distinct method already applied. How can I take this groupBy method, and correctly apply it as an extension to be able to use it like `const groupItems = myItems.groupBy(item => item.key)`?

Existing extension code:

```
export { };
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        distinct(): Array<T>;
    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.distinct) {
    Array.prototype.distinct = function <T>(): T[] {
        const stringifiedItems = this.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item));
        const set = new Set(stringifiedItems);
        return Array.from(set).map((item) => JSON.parse(item));
    };
}
```

Comment: [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342870/extending-javascripts-built-in-types-is-it-evil#comment67946348_40342870)! But if you absolutely have to, a) [do it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572) and b) don't do it in an `if` statement which will cause your code to break if javascript should ever get a native method of that name

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with this code:

```
export { };
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        distinct(): Array<T>;
        // Add the interface declaration
        groupBy(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => string): { [key: string]: T[] }
    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.distinct) {
    Array.prototype.distinct = function <T>(): T[] {
        const stringifiedItems = this.map((item) => JSON.stringify(item));
        const set = new Set(stringifiedItems);
        return Array.from(set).map((item) => JSON.parse(item));
    };
}

// Add it to the prototype
if (!Array.prototype.groupBy) {
    Array.prototype.groupBy = function <T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => string) {
        return this.reduce((acc, value, index, array) => {
            (acc[predicate(value, index, array)] ||= []).push(value);
            return acc;
        }, {} as { [key: string]: T[] });
    }
}
```